# Get points of field in the image with mouse javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I get a `points` (x,y) of field image size with mouse in javascript or jQuery?

Example:
I have a image in my page and in the image has some fields, when I click and drag with mouse on the field I need get `points` of square formed.

These is necessary because I'll insert this

I researched some examples, but not found.

Comment: You should explain more i think. where are you dragging the image to ? what points do you want ?

Comment: @YoYo I scanned an imagem and set some fields, for example filed _name_ in image, for me set this field I need go in the image on _name_ field and click and drag with mouse upon field. I know events click in javascript but how can I get delimiters (x,y) **points** formed by the rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

your question is not clear but if you just want image size you can do by this :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var img = $('img');

  img.removeAttr("width"); 

  img.removeAttr("height");

  alert( img.width() );
  alert( img.height() );
});
```